# Can't Resolve "! Missing \endcsname inserted" Error with tikzcd Package

Tags: errors, tikz-cd

I've read the other questions on this site corresponding to the same error and I just don't understand why I can't resolve the issue on my machine.  Here is essentially what my code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\normalem
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url,graphicx,tabularx,array,geometry}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xcolor, listings}
%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
%\usepackage{mcode}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbb{0} \arrow[d, “!”] \arrow[r, “!”] & \mathbb{1} \arrow[d, “\bot”] \\
\mathbb{1} \arrow [r, “\top”] & \Omega
\end{tikzcd}
\]


\end{document}
```

The specific error I get reads:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \OT1\textquotedblleft 
l.91 \end{tikzcd}
```

Is there a problem with my library declarations?  I can't tell what about my diagram might be off.  Troubleshooting suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need straight ascii " not left and right double quotes:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbb{0} \arrow[d, "!"] \arrow[r, "!"] & \mathbb{1} \arrow[d, "\bot"] \\
\mathbb{1} \arrow [r, "\top"] & \Omega
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Comment: Ahh, interesting.  Can this be adjusted in the editor I'm using?  I'm in TeXWorks, my keyboard just defaults to the left and right double quotes.

Comment: sorry I know nothing about texworks but I would be very surprised if any editor designed for tex makes it hard to insert `"` @Mnifldz

Comment: Thanks, got it working.  It was in fact some formatting preset in the editor.